# BASH: How to echo output from function that edits global variable

Tags: bash

In general, how do one echo the output from a function while that function is editing a global variable? What's the best practice here?

I've tried calling the function in a subshell as an argument to echo. But then the global variable is not edited for the parent environment.

```
declare -a ARR
f () {
  ARR+=("$1")
  echo "added $1"
}
echo $(f a)
f b
f c
echo "${ARR[@]}"
```

I expect the output:

```
added a
added b
added c
a b c
```

But I'm getting

```
added a
added b
added c
b c
```

Comment: `echo $(f a)` changes array variable in a subshell and that change is not available in parent shell.

Comment: `subshell as an argument to echo. But then the global variable is not edited` - that's exactly how a subshell works.

Comment: Do not use a global variable. Maybe something like `g() { printf "%s " "$1" >> g.all; echo "added $1"; }` and check `g.all` when finished.

Answer (score 1):

> how do one echo the output from a function while that function is editing a global variable?

You can use a temporary file:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
f > "$tmp"
output="$(<"$tmp")"
rm "$output"
echo "$output"
```

> What's the best practice here?

This is subjective and opinion based. Don't grab the output of a function. If you have a function that modifies global state, why not pass the output using some global variable, too?

```
f() {
   declare -g -a ARR
   ARR+=("$1")
   declare -g f_log
   f_log+="added $1"
}
f
echo "$f_log"
```

Leave the `stdout` of a function for some logging and error reporting. There is no reason to grab the function output, it's already a function, it can modify the state of the program in any way.

Side note:

I recently tried to interleave stdout of a function for data and output and I did this:

```
f() {
    source /dev/stdin <<<"$1"
    shift 1
    ARR+=("$1")
    declare -p ARR
    echo
    echo "added $1"
}
tmp=$(f "$(declare -p ARR)" a)
source /dev/stdin < <(<<<"$tmp" sed -n '0,/^$/p')
echo "$(<<<"$tmp" sed '0,/^$/d')"
```

which actually adds more hassle then it's worth.

Comment: Thanks! So the idea of a function in Bash s not to take input and produce output? Is the idea of a function to edit the program state only through global variables?

Comment: It looks like way over-simplification. The "idea" of function is to give programmers flexibility in designing their program flow. So you can do what you want. The question remains on "what you want". My opinion is, that best functions are such that don't touch global variables at all, only transform `stdin + arguments -> stdout` basis. My second code snippets tries to mix variables and data within a single stdout mix, by separating them with an empty newline and filtering stdout after that. Designing object-oriented principles in bash is hard, variables don't have scope, its hard to pass state

Comment: It's easier to work on global variables when designing OOP in bash, you can find many examples online. I usually go with passing object state using a text name that I suffix with some string and use that global variable for a state, like `obj_do() { declare -g "$1"_state; # use and update "$1"_state; };` and call it with  `obj_do 'obj1' 'some arg'`.